# RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded Vue router

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

I want to write a login with vue js to do this, I wrote this first

[image]

And

[image]

And I got this error (Range Error: Maximum call stack size exceeded)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think Your `beforeEach` also runs for `login`, so it enters an endless loop redirecting to `/login` over and over.

Try to add one more condition like below:-

```
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  let isAuthenticate = false;

  if(localStorage.getItem('user')) {
    isAuthenticate = true;
  } 
  if(isAuthenticate && to.name !== 'login') {
    next();
  } else if(isAuthenticate) {
    next('/Dashboard/home')
  } else if(to.name === 'login') {
    next();
  } else {
    next('login')
  }
})
```